# Max-min genus of a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, embeddings, genus

As usual, the genus of a graph with a prescribed circular ordering of the edges at each vertex is defined as the minimum genus of an orientable surface in which the graph can be drawn without edge crossings and with these orderings respected.
The maximum genus and minimum genus of a graph (without prescribed orderings) are well-studied parameters, which give the maximum/minimum genus of the graph over all possible choices of circular edge ordering.

I am interested in the following variant: let $G$ be a bipartite graph on $m + n$ nodes, and define the *max-min genus* $\gamma_{mm}(G)$ as follows.
First Player 1, who is trying to maximize genus, picks a circular ordering of the edges at each of the $m$ nodes on the left.
Then Player 2, who is trying to minimize genus, views Player 1's choice and picks a circular ordering of the edges at each of the $n$ nodes on the right.
Then $\gamma_{mm}(G)$ is defined as the genus of $G$ after orderings are fixed under optimal play.

> Has this been studied before?  In particular: what estimates on $\gamma_{mm}(G)$ apply as a function of $m, n$?  I am interested in results along the lines of $\gamma_{mm}(G) \le f(m, n)$ for some function $f$.

The trivial bound is $\gamma_{mm}(G) \le \lfloor \beta(G) / 2 \rfloor$, where $\beta(G)$ is the rank of its cycle space (since this is the [upper bound](https://books.google.com/books?id=-7Q_POGh-2cC&pg=PA661#v=onepage&q&f=false) on $\gamma_{max}(G)$).
I am particularly interested in results that improve asymptotically on this.

Comment: Is there a reason to restrict this definition to bipartitie graphs? If there exist edges between Player 1's vertices, do these not matter somehow?

Comment: It also seems interesting to me to consider the same question where either player is allowed to determine the cyclic ordering around any vertex when it is their turn.

Comment: The reason I've restricted attention to bipartite graphs is that otherwise player 1 can ensure that $\gamma_{max}$ of an $m$-node graph (roughly equal to the number of edges between m-nodes) will sometimes be necessary, and so the best possible asymptotic upper bound for my question would be $\gamma_{mm}(G) = O(m^2)$.